# Is this community suitable for non-professionals?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am not a professional, but an amateur, mostly a user of CLI tools like FFmpeg or open source apps, like Avidemux or Shotcut.

Is it OK for people like me to post questions here?

Comment: What DrMayhem said. Though I'd like to add that like with every SE site, a bit of research on your side before asking a question is expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course it is! It is intended to be a site where enthusiasts can learn from experienced professionals and other enthusiasts.

Comment: The one thing I would add is to be aware that it is a subset of the community.  Most professional editors rarely use CLI tools other than for possibly transcoding, because they have very low usability compared to the more common NLE environments.  We do have a pretty alive section of people who work on mostly CLI based stuff though, it just sometimes takes a bit longer to get answers since fewer people can answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that a lot of ffmpeg questions get asked on SuperUser rather than VideoProduction - I'm guessing that stems from the way that ffmpeg is used often on web servers to process video, so it's on-topic for the SuperUser crowd. That said, I'm a video post-production professional who uses ffmpeg and sox and so on every day.

Comment: The issue you are arising is a very interesting one. 
Maybe that many of them simply do not know about this site and some kind of promotion should take place, perhaps linking to some answers here. I tend to not like Superuser because by its own nature attracts the jacks of all trades and  masters of none. It is better to use a specialised site, when available. IMHO many Superuser video users would be happy to be addressed here.